# How large is the QGIS community?

Tags: qgis

How large is the QGIS community?  I'm interested in understanding the shift from traditional proprietary software to open sourced solutions.

Comment: I asked a similar question a few months ago: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21858/looking-for-market-share-of-gis-desktop-tools

Answer (score 2):

Download stats are one way to look at it: http://linfiniti.com/2011/10/qgis-1-7-0-download-stats/

There is also a user map if you are interested in geographic distribution of users http://plugins.qgis.org/community-map/

But all these can only capture a small part of the whole community.